# Shortcut to create new equation in Word 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2011

What is the shortcut to create a new equation in Word 2011?

I have looked [at this shortcut list](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/12/en-us/word/item/f7701a9f-35bc-49c5-a5b5-8c24b085a166), but it does not include that.

Comment: First method does work but it is language sensitive (what a mess). So for an example on a danish installation you would need to replace "Equation" with "Ligning".

Comment: For PC users, in Microsoft Word 2010, it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to create an equation in your document.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Inserting a new Equation:

Go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, and set up an Application shortcut for Microsoft Word.

As the menu item's title, use "Equation".

[image]

This will add a new equation to the document:

[image]

---

#### Opening the Equation editor:

Go to *Tools » Customize Keyboard*. Here, create a new shortcut for *Insert » InsertEquation*.

For example, I've used <kbd>Command-Shift-E</kbd>. Make sure you click *Assign*, then *OK*.

[image]

Comment: This opens the Equation Editor in a new window, I want to use the inline one, that can normally be inserted by going to "Document Elements" in the ribbon and clicking on Equation.

Answer (score 12):

For me with Word for Mac 2011, inserting equation shortcut is already set as: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: How do I type a `=` in a shortcut with a danish keyboard? I need to press `shift`+`0` to type a `=`. Neither `ctrl`+`0` or `ctrl`+`shift`+`0` works for me. I also tried with command instead of control.

Comment: @Tyilo, you might have stumbled on the nuts and bolts of a new question there.  Just saying, you'd likely get more attention than having what amounts to a new question in a comment.

Comment: You can also toggle Equation on highlighted text using Ctrl+=.